# dockerized jenkins failed building dockerfile work dir issue

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers, continuous-integration

I have a jenkins container and a pipeline which consist of building docker images. I have mounted the necessary mounts (/var/run/docker.sock, /var/run) for jenkins to use docker commands. I also bind mounted a folder from my host to jenkins as its workspace directory (/var/jenkins_home/workspace).

Here is the Dockerfile which is part of my project:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
 WORKDIR /app
 EXPOSE 80

 FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
 WORKDIR /src
 RUN hostname && pwd
 COPY /storage/admin/jenkins/workspace/tremplinx_master-NAUVRHOZ5IJBBHVQ54PTEZJJL33WO7NMFUYS5BF3C5H3LBCDC3XA/SPA/SPA.csproj SPA/SPA.csproj
 RUN dotnet restore SPA/SPA.csproj
 COPY . .
 WORKDIR /src/SPA
 RUN dotnet build SPA.csproj -c Release -o /app
```

Running my pipeline fail with the following error:

```
[tremplinx_master-NAUVRHOZ5IJBBHVQ54PTEZJJL33WO7NMFUYS5BF3C5H3LBCDC3XA] Running shell script

+ docker build -t spa:dev-0.0.1 SPA/

Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.536MB


Step 1/17 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base

 ---> 625b44243fbe

Step 2/17 : WORKDIR /app

 ---> Using cache

 ---> 8279155deb77

Step 3/17 : EXPOSE 80

 ---> Using cache

 ---> 574345928687

Step 4/17 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build

 ---> f6d6062f4612

Step 5/17 : WORKDIR /src

 ---> Using cache

 ---> b49549e644ac

Step 6/17 : COPY /storage/admin/jenkins/workspace/tremplinx_master-NAUVRHOZ5IJBBHVQ54PTEZJJL33WO7NMFUYS5BF3C5H3LBCDC3XA/SPA/SPA.csproj SPA/SPA.csproj

COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder969545350/storage/admin/jenkins/workspace/tremplinx_master-NAUVRHOZ5IJBBHVQ54PTEZJJL33WO7NMFUYS5BF3C5H3LBCDC3XA/SPA/SPA.csproj: no such file or directory

script returned exit code 1
```

I can't figure out why docker is using /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder969545350... folder whereas I have specified the full path containing my project.
I'm new to Jenkins so forgive me if I forgot to specify important information .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my issue. I had to change the way I call my Dockerfile and changing the WORKDIR inside.

Comment: Can you be more specific with the resolution? I have the same issue.

Comment: Files and directories from the COPY step should be within the build context. From the [Dockerfile reference/COPY section](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) : 

"The <src> path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon."